# How to make a regexp that have a start point and a end point, with any content in it

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to know how to write an RegularExpression that have an start point - some content - and an end point.

My try was this one:

```
"["<DT><A"+\w*"</A>"+]"
```

But it didn’t work ... this is my first try with RegExp.

```
As start point i need "<DT><A"
As end point this one "</A>"
```

The content between this did not matter.

Hope someone could help me.

Btw. I tried this in Notepad ++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match from the start of `<DT><A`, the content in between, and then the ending `</A>`.
You could simply use the following if you do not have newline sequences in between.

```
Find: <DT><A(.*?)</A>
```

If you do have newline sequences in between the start and end.

```
Find: <DT><A([\S\s]*?)</A>
```

If you have quotes surrounding your start and ending tags, you can use the following.

```
Find: "<DT><A"([^"]*)"</A>"
```

Comment: @hwnd the second regular expression will not work on values like <DT><A href='someurl.com'><B>bold link</B></A>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find anything between

```
<DT><A and </A>
```

you can use match non-word `\W` and word `\w` enclosed with the brackets `[\w\W]` and the asterisks to match anything.  The `?` will apply the greedy match and should restrict it to the earlier match.

Then enclose that with the start and end values that you are looking for.  This will match anything until it finds the first matching `</A>` tag.

```
<DT><A[\w\W]*?</A>
```